# mod_jk/isapi_redirect not loading settings

Tags: iis, tomcat, mod-jk, isapi

I'm setting up the IIS version of mod_jk so I can redirect requests to a Tomcat instance.  Running IIS 6 on Win2k3 server on a Xeon 64-bit CPU.  I'm running the AMD64 version of isapi_redirect.dll.

It seems that for some reason the .dll is not reading any of my settings.  I've tried both using registry settings and putting an isapi_redirect.properties file in the directory with the DLL and neither work.  I know that everything else is configured properly because it's properly forwarding requests (i.e. it's working!).  It seems that if everything is in the default location it works but the minute I try to move something it doesn't.

I'm also not seeing a log file pop up in the expected location (c:\tomcat\logs\isapi.log), but I'm guessing this is because the default log level is set to error and no errors are occurring.

Any ideas as to how to get this to pick up my settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for Windows Events?. There can be issue with isapi_redirect.dll failing to read.

Comment: Yes there are no errors.  Like I said... my connection forwarding is working, I just can't get it to use anything except the default settings.